# Google Play : App installs, but doesn't load

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console, google-play-games

My App got rejected by Google today because ,,App installs, but doesn't load"

I tested the app on multiple devices and I never had an error like this!
Does anyone know a soultion for this? (its made with unity)

Comment: Have you tried to launch your app on low-end devices?

Comment: No, because I don't have any low end device

Comment: that can be the issue actually. create the debug build and check your app data in profiler. especially memory consumed by your app.

Comment: Hey, found out, that it's because the prices of the IAP isn't loading do you have any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Start by deploying the app on the internal testing track, and then review the pre-launch reports. These reports will provide valuable information such as crash logs, screenshots, and video recordings of any crashes. Utilizing this data is crucial in addressing and resolving issues effectively.

Answer (score 0):

The rejection email should have a screenshot of where the issue is. There are different reasons why the app doesn't load. You can check the crash reports or other tools like Crashlytics (if you are using them) to see if there is a crash as well.

Another option would be to download the build from the Bundle explorer and run it locally on your machine or create a release build from your code. You should be able to check if you can replicate the issue and/or see logs.

Reference: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/thread/237294252/working-application-denied-for-app-installs-but-doesn-t-load?hl=en